# G-Mail Extensions For Labels And Filters

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, email

I have a new GMail address for my business, which will have it's own magazine, and I want to set up the email addresses for this part of the business.

So I set up the filters : `Magazine` , `Magazine/Contact` & `Magazine/Issues` : And it's the `Magazine/Issues` I'm wanting to extend.

So for `Magazine/Issues` I have:

- Label : `Magazine/Issues`
- Account/Import : `My Name <business+magazine.issues@gmail.com>`
- A filter connecting the `Account` to the `Label`.

So this is fine, but I would like to make it a bit more dynamic by adding a number to the issue in `Label` and `Account` - So:

- Label : `Magazine/Issues/ ( * )`
- Account/Import : `My Name <business+magazine.issues.( * )@gmail.com>`

This way I can let my visitors send me a gmail to `business+magazine.issues.5@gmail.com` - For example.

But, I don't want to have to set up a new extension to each label for every issue - **Is this possible**?